# Sharepoint 2013 Custom masterpage ad communties

Tags: 2013, master-page, community

I have created a custom masterpage which is set to be a 'Site' masterpage and not a system master page. I have a community which I have built using community web parts.

When I add a comment to a topic, the masterpage which is rendered with the add topic web part is not my custom masterpage.

How do I ensure that all pages in SharePoint 2013 use my custom masterpage?

Comment: Moe i have hit an issue marking this question as the answer, i posted as dom and i have now registered but i cannot see the 'answer' question button, any ideas because it works Woot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Site Master Pages are only used on publishing pages. This excludes e.g. the views of lists (NewForm.aspx, AllItems.aspx, etc.).
Also while viewing a topic the page is based on a web part Site Page, i.e. not a publishing page.

If you'd like to have custom master pages used on these non publishing pages, you could edit the .aspx -file of the selected pages to use your master page. Briefly put the instructions would be:

1. Open your community site on SharePoint Designer
2. Open `Site Pages` -> `Topic.aspx` -> Edit file
3. From the ribbon row select *Advanced Mode*
4. Most likely from row no. 2 you'll find *`MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"`*. Edit this to refer to your custom master page file (e.g. *`"~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomMasterPage.master"`*)
5. Save the changes
6. Repeat steps 2-5 on `DispForm.aspx` (etc.) found on `Lists and Libraries` -> `Discussions List` and on whichever .aspx files you find necessary

Notes:

- I have **not** tested this solution in this scenario.
- Sometimes when you edit a page in Advanced Mode an informative text `The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.` shows up on the page. One way to get rid of the message is [explained on entrance's blog](http://www.entrancesoftware.com/2013/04/23/sharepoint-consultant-tip-removing-revert-to-template/).

Comment: Hi, my site is a publishing site with custom page layouts which have web parts that make up a community, when i want to a comment to a topic my masterpage is not used.

Comment: Just clearing up: So your custom master page is used on the "community main page" which shows the topics etc.? But it's not used when you for example open a topic?

Comment: Thats correct, I have created a custom masterpage, and then a custom page layout, i have then added 'Community' web parts to that custom page layout but when i open a topic the default SP2013 masterpage is displayed with the topic web part on the page. hope this makes sense, thanks

Comment: That's because the page showing your community web parts is a publishing page, which uses the Site Master Pages. However the view of your topics is actually a Site Page (OOTB /_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Community%20Discussion/AllItems.aspx) and opened topic is a list item opened in a site page format too. These have nothing to do with publishing pages and thus they obey the set System Master Page.

Comment: Hi Moe, thanks for the info, this helps explain why my style is not applied but can you give some advice on how i can modify the style of AllItems.aspx so that i dont have to set the system master page as my custom master page because i am using a Fixed width 1024px and it causes issues when i have overflows in web parts etc with the Admin view. Ultimately i need to style all pages on an adhoc basis whether they are system pages or not. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Find my updated answer above.

Comment: Your a gentlemen and a scollar, i will test this out today after I've patched AppFabric and report back. Thanks Dom