# SharePoint 2013 - Customization site pages only, within a specific sub site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

From SharePoint 2013 -If I create a publishing sub site called "Media"  and I want to customize the master page for all **site pages** within this **Media** sub site, what steps must I take to complete this without changing the administrative pages (i.e. pages in site settings, design manager, etc...).  They all use olso.

I want a full customization (master page editing), of just the site pages within this specific sub site.

I may have 100 site pages within this sub site, and want them all to use a single custom master template.  Nothing else in this sub site should use this custom master template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you already know how to go about customizing your master page.

To just set a custom master page for the application pages of the subsite, go to **Site Settings** --> **Look and Feel** --> **Master page** and from there change the **Site Master Page** from

*Inherit site master page from parent of this site*

to

*Specify a master page to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it*

and select your custom master page from the dropdown. If you don't see your custom masterpage in the dropdown, make sure your custom masterpage is uploaded in the **Site Settings** --> **Web Designer Galleries** --> **Master pages and page layouts gallery** and is approved.

Doing the above will just change the masterpage for the application pages, the system/admin pages will still use the oslo masterpage.

Comment: These steps will chanage the Publishing pages - not the site pages (if community features are enabled inside a publishing site).  I want to do the reverse...I want to change the master page for site pages only - not publishing pages.  To back this up answer is also here - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110096/sharepoint-2013-custom-masterpage-ad-communties